# How to transfer data from cloud vm to usb drive

Tags: linux, azure, cloud, virtual-machine, data-transfer

I want to copy data from cloud vm to my pc or usb device. I am using azure cloud and linux vm.Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Your question is offtopic, too broad and unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Given this is a Linux Based System , one of the best ways to get files out of the Linux VM is by setting up FTP Server in your Linux VM. The steps of Setting Linux VM is detailed here (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/holgerkenn/archive/2014/03/19/setting-up-a-linux-ftp-server-on-windows-azure.aspx)

After you have setup the FTP Server you can access the files via any FTP Client.